# Websockets abstraction / compatibility

Tags: websocket

As Websockets are not allways implemented nowadays, some libraries try to circumvent this with the Flash plugin for example. However, that is not always available, and there are Websocket-like features with Ajax connections in frameworks too. However, is there an Websocket standard conforming abstraction library that provides a reliable Websocket in any cases? Eg. cross-browser, firewall safe etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) is probably the closest thing. There is a primary server implementation in Node.js but Socket.IO can also be thought of as a higher level protocol layer that can use various transports underneath (with WebSockets being preferred) and as such there are other implementations of Socket.IO servers in other languages.